# Could not start PSEXESVC service on 134.134.134.10: The stub received bad data

Tags: c#, process, psexec

i have a C# code with a process running PsExec on remote machine and the outcome is Could not start PSEXESVC service on 134.134.134.10:
The stub received bad data.

i understood its an issue of the remote machine but i'm that close to just throw it to the garbage. please does anyone know whats the root of this issue?

thanks.

Comment: Does https://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-problems_topic23597.html help?

Comment: no, it works on other machines. just one that gives me this error. im desperate.